# Dual boot error

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-one, ubuntu-gnome, ubuntu-core, time

so I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and it dual boots with Windows 10 Pro on my laptop. Everything is fine until the point when I switch between the two systems by restarting the computer. The time displayed on Ubuntu will be 3 hours ahead of the actual time while in Windows it will be 3 hours behind the actual time.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by Windows storing the time in local time, and Linux storing the time in UTC.  You have 2 options:

1. Change your time zone in Windows to UTC.
2. Tell linux to store the time in local time with the following command.

`timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock`

Comment: Hey sir, thanks for the solutions above but they're setting my time to UTC but my time zone is UTC+3. How do I go about it?